# Most efficient way to remove a range of rows from a DenseMatrix?

Tags: scala-breeze

I want to remove rows `M+1` through `N` in a DenseMatrix (`DM_a` below), to produce another DenseMatrix (`DM_b`). Something like this:

```
                               K
DM_a =   0 +-------------------+
           |                   |
           |                   |
           |                   |
         M |                   |
           |                   |
           |                   |
           |                   |
         N +-------------------+



                               K
DM_b =   0 +-------------------+
           |                   |
           |                   |
           |                   |
         M +-------------------+
```

Is it best (most efficient) to do this with slicing like this: `val DM_b = DM_a(0 to M, ::)` or should I map `padRight` to each column of `DM_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matrix slice:

```
  DM_a(0 until M, ::)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So, what's the difference between the `to` and `until` versions of the slice?

Comment: to is inclusive, until is exclusive (note that the parameters to a slice are just scala.Range objects)

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. So then, wouldn't I want `0 to M` since I wanted to remove the rows beginning with row `M+1`? Or alternatively, I guess I'd need `0 until M+1`, right?